# List all files and folders in a specific subdirectory from Firebase Cloud Storage through Python

Tags: python, firebase, cloud-storage, pyrebase

I would like to list all the files and folders in a specific directory inside firebase cloud storage. I have tried using `files = storage.list_files()` from other stack overflow answers. This lists all the files and folders. I have tried using `files = storage.list_files(prefix='images/')` but it does not work.

I am using pyrebase4 to initialize the app and I have even provided serviceAccount but it did not work.

```
bucket = storage.bucket()
bucket.list_blobs(prefix="files/")
```

Please respond with the libraries you are importing, the syntax of initializing firebase app and finally the code to fetch list of all files from a specific directory in firebase cloud storage.

If the above is not possible, would it be very resource demanding (time & cost) to do a `storage.list_files().includes(file_to_be_searched)` every time? for let's say, 10k total files.

Answer (score 0):

The example provided is using the firebase admin sdk for python.

Given that you said you are using pyrebase you'd have to use pyrebase

```py
import pyrebase

# configure firebase app
config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://projectId.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com",
# DO NOT FORGET SERVICE ACCOUNT
"serviceAccount":"path to service account"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()

# specify directory path
directory_path = "path/to/directory"

# list files in directory
files = storage.list_files(directory_path)

# print file names
for file in files:
    print(file.name)
```

> would it be very resource demanding (time & cost)

Yes it will to both.

Comment: It throws an error: `TypeError: Storage.list_files() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: see my list files above , I used an argument

Comment: I ran the same code as you provided, only changing the directory to a root folder - "files". It shows me the same error, and if I pass a "None" with directory_path, it shows `TypeError: Storage.list_files() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`. So it's a problem with pyrebase API?

The whole error for your code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Git_code\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    files = storage.list_files(directory_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Storage.list_files() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the code works by running it on your end? I am sure I have done everything the same and it does not work.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need a service account. I have updated my answer

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have added a service account. It still says that `Storage.list_files() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` even though I am only providing `directory_path` as a parameter. Can you confirm that it works on your end?

Comment: Tried with service account and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the list_files() will always list all the files because it is deprecated. [https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/414#issuecomment-1100009426](https://nvm,%20the%20feature%20is%20deprecated.%20https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/414#issuecomment-1100009426)

This code should work to list all the files and folders in a specific directory (copying from the link mentioned above).

```
$ pip install pyrebase
$ pip install pyrebase4

import pyrebase

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()

path = "images/"
files = storage.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=path)

# print file names
for file in files:
    print(file.name)
```